# How to create list from 100 elements to list of 10

Tags: python, list, average, mean

I have small brain fade today and I believe it will be faster to get hint here than wondering for an hour.

I have list A of 100 elements. How can I create another list(B) basing on list A, that will have 10 elements, so that each element is mean of 10 elements from  list A?

Thank you in advance.

```
e.g.

A = [10,10,10,10,10,20,20,20,20,20,30,30,30,30,30,40,40,40,40,40]
B = [15, 35]
```

Comment: Is the list ordered? Did you try looping through it?

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [i for i in range(100)]
[sum(A[k * 10 : 10*(k+1)])/10 for k in range(len(A)//10)]
```

Output

```
[4.5, 14.5, 24.5, 34.5, 44.5, 54.5, 64.5, 74.5, 84.5, 94.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
A = [10,10,10,10,10,20,20,20,20,20,30,30,30,30,30,40,40,40,40,40]
B = [sum(A[i:i+10])/10 for i in range(0, len(A), 10)]

print(B)
# [15.0, 35.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [10,10,10,10,10,20,20,20,20,20,30,30,30,30,30,40,40,40,40,40]
B = []

for i in range (0,int(len(A)/10)):
    numbersSum = sum(A[i*10:(i+1)*10])/10
    print(numbersSum)
    B.append(numbersSum)
print(B)
```

Comment: much complex one.